# Flow control for a function periodically returning None

Tags: python

I have a function `getPrices()` that return `None` sometimes and a dictionary most of the time .

When calling it I want to pass when it returns `None` and do something when it actually returns a dictionary.

This is how I go about it :

```
if getPrices() is None:
    pass
else:
    if getPrices().items():
        for key, value in getPrices().items():
            <do something>
```

Now, this is obviously wrong , since I'm still getting this error sporadically

```
if getPrices().items(): 
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'items'
```

How would you properly handle the `getPrices()` function returning `None`?

Comment: `return None sometimes and a dictionary most of the time`, so calling it twice would most probably return different output. Right? Unless we can see the function, that's a doubt.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem here is that you *keep calling* `getPrices()`, each time it may `return` a different `dict` or `None`.

```
if getPrices() is None: # first call
    pass
else:
    if getPrices().items(): # second call
        for key, value in getPrices().items(): # third call
```

Instead, you should store the resulting value for processing:

```
value = getPrices()
if value is not None:
    for key, value in value.items():
        # do your stuff
```

Answer (score 2):

As your `getPrices` function does not always return the same thing, calling it several times will return different results. Consider for instance:

```
def getPrices():
   return random.random()
```

Obviously, some code like:

```
if getPrices() > 0.5:
    print getPrices()
```

will sometimes return values less than 0.5. Similarly, you want to do something like:

```
prices = getPrices()
if prices is None:
   ...
else:
   ...
```

Or better still:

```
 prices = getPrices()
 if hasattr(prices, 'items'):
     items = prices.items()
     ...
 else:
     log.warning("Prices is not a dictionary !")
     ...
```

Comment: The fact that `getPrices()` is a function (or any other callable FWIW) doesn't **necessarily** imply it will return different results on each call.

Answer (score 1):

Or perhaps just catch the error:

```
try:
    for key, value in getPrices().items():
        <do something>
except AttributeError:
    #log error
    #cleanup
```

Answer (score 0):

rather than calling and recalling your functions several times, it's good practice to assign it to a variable.

```
pricesDict = getPrices()
if pricesDict is not None:
    for key, value in prices.items():
        <do something>
```